# Should View be allowed to open another View in MVVM

Tags: mvvm

Lets take this example. I have a AView which is bound to AViewModel. AView should execute an ACommand on AViewModel, and pass it a parameter. The problem is that ViewA doesnt have enough information to pass to command, so another BView needs to be displayed, in order to gather information from the user. After the VIewB is closed, ViewA invokes ACommand on AViewModel, and passes parameter to it.

How to handle this scenario? Should I allow AView to communicate directly to BView, or I am breaking some rule if I do so?

Another way I am thinking is to invoke a ACommand on AViewModel without a parameter, then from VIewModelA send a message that a information is required to complete the task. This information is captured by MainPageViewModel, than sends a request to open BView, which is bound to BViewModel. When BView is closed, a BVIewModel sends a message with additional info, and ViewModelA has subscribed to this type of message, so it receives it, and completes the task. Pretty complicated for just entering values in two text boxes, right? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 golden rules to MVVM: `Separation, Separation & Separation` :)

Reasons include: Automated testing of components, complete separation of functionality (e.g. for independent modules), independent team development of modules (without tripping over each other) and generally just easier to figure out *what does what*.

**In answer to your interconnecting two Views:** you are adding dependencies that should not exist. Separation of concerns is more important than a little complexity (*and I would argue that the messaging model is less complex than maintaining a direct interconnection*).

The complexity of publishing/listening for an extra message is nothing compared to the harm of interconnecting unrelated components so your last suggestion is "better", but I would actually suggest a cleaner approach to the whole problem:

### A few guidelines:

- Views should not know where their data comes from, only how to display a certain shape of data. Command execution is via bindings to ICommands on the VM.
- ViewModels should hold a certain shape of data and commands. It should have no idea where the data comes from or what is binding to it.
- Models hold the actual data, but have no idea where it is consumed.
- Controllers (often overlooked in MVVM) register/push events, populate VMs from models, set the code in ICommands, control visibility of views etc. Controllers are the only thing actually required to stay in memory at all times and they are quite slim (mostly code & little data).

Basically I would suggest adding Controllers to your MVVM pattern (MVCVM?). App/modules create and initialize controllers. Controllers subscribe to events and provide the logic of the application.

Try this pattern and see how simple it becomes to work with lots of Views, ViewModels and Models. *You do not mention what language or framework you are using, so I can't make specific suggestions for examples.*

Comment: Hi, I am sorry for late response, but its seems that SO doesnt like to notify me about any responses. :) Anyway I am using c# and MVVMLight framework, so any link about what exactly are Controllers is greate. I have never heard of them before, related to MVVM.

Comment: @Goran: Might have to write up something myself. A controller is nothing but a class containing your logic. When initialized it subscribes to any messages of interest to it. When something happens (e.g. via code it placed in an ICommand) it publishes a message for other controllers to hear. A controller is where your app logic belongs. It makes the apps very flexible and have a good *separation of concerns*.

Comment: What is the benefit of having this further separation, than just having business logic in ViewModel, as it is proposed by MVVM design pattern? I publish messages in VM, VM gets data from the repository, my Commands are in VM... VM mabages Views through ScreenConductors...

Comment: ViewModels hold a certain shape of data... and that's all. They should not care where it comes from or who is using it. If you put logic in your VM, then in order to respond (e.g. to messages), the lifespan of the VM has to change, whereas a controller lives much longer and does not carry the memory overhead of the data. There is a code generator called Sculpture that uses this pattern and it really does make your apps more flexible/reusable/understandable. Once you start using separate controllers in MVVM you will wonder why you ever tried to make your VMs into controllers. Give it a try! :)

Comment: I've seen several people suggest using controllers with MVVM but I haven't seen any great examples given in how it improves complex applications. My concern is that from your definition "Controllers (often overlooked in MVVM) register/push events, populate VMs from models, set the code in ICommands, control visibility of views etc" it appears that controllers easily violate SRP.